# Why is my Swift Program stalling and not running?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, uiview, xcode6

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    func shuffle<C: MutableCollectionType where C.Index == Int>(var list: C) -> C {
    let c = count(list)
    for i in 0..<(c - 1) {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(c - i))) + i
        swap(&list[i], &list[j])
    }
    return list
}
@IBOutlet weak var backround: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Earthy: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Blocker: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var asteroid5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var asteroid4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var asteroid3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var asteroid2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var asteroid1: UIImageView!


let realAsteroid = UIImage(named: "Asteroid")
        var numberArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var playerScore = 0
var aliveOrNah:Bool = true
var positioningNumRock = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1
var positioningNumBlocker = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1

        //set random numbers
override func viewDidLoad(){

    var shuffledNumArray:Array = shuffle(numberArray)
    println(shuffledNumArray)
    var but1String:String = shuffledNumArray[0]
    var but2String:String = shuffledNumArray[1]
    var but3String:String = shuffledNumArray[2]
    var but4String:String = shuffledNumArray[3]
    var but5String:String = shuffledNumArray[4]


    self.button1.setTitle(but1String,forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.button2.setTitle(but2String,forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.button3.setTitle(but3String,forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.button4.setTitle(but4String,forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.button5.setTitle(but5String,forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    var posRandNum = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1

    func offWithTheRocks(){
    switch posRandNum{
    case 1:
        self.asteroid1.center.y += view.bounds.height
        UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
            self.asteroid1.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height - 100
        })



    case 2:

        self.asteroid2.center.y += view.bounds.height
        UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
                self.asteroid2.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height - 100
            })


    case 3:

            self.asteroid3.center.y += view.bounds.height
            UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
                self.asteroid3.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height - 100
            })


    case 4:

            self.asteroid4.center.y += view.bounds.height
            UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
                self.asteroid4.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height - 100
            })


    case 5:

            self.asteroid5.center.y += view.bounds.height

                        UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
                self.asteroid5.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height - 100
            })



    default:
        break
    }
    }
```

}

}

This code builds successfully but whenever I hit the play button to move onto the this View the program stalls and the code above will not run. Any suggestions? Anyone know what I did wrong? I am a beginner so I am aware that I could have made a dumb mistake or something.

Comment: Can you narrow down, with breakpoints or debug logging, where it is stalling?

Answer (score 1):

The switch/case code will never run, because you have placed it inside a function declaration `func offWithTheRocks(){ ... }` and that function is never called.  Try deleting `func offWithTheRocks(){` and the associated trailing `}`.